# How do I get source highlighting via source-highlight for most?

Tags: terminal, syntax-highlighting, pager, most

I can get source highlighting to work with `lesspipe` or GNU `source-highlight`, but both depend on environment variables that are specific to `less`. How would I get syntax highlighting in most?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't do that: **`most`** has no option for passing-through escape sequences which it partially-interprets.  It will either treat the input as a *binary* file (which you wouldn't want), or as a *text* file.  For the latter, it recognizes overstruck text (using backspaces), and can render **those** with a particular color.  But that falls short of what's generally meant by **syntax highlighting**.